# Does deleting INDEX delete TABLE ? IN SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle

IF I FIRE A QUERY IN SQLPLS
DROP INDEX ord_customer_ix_demo;

This statement drops an index named ord_customer_ix_demo, which was created in "Compressing an Index: Example":

does this drop my table too?

I FIREd A QUERY IN SQLPLS
DROP INDEX ord_customer_ix_demo;

This statement drops an index named ord_customer_ix_demo, which was created in "Compressing an Index: Example":

i want to know does this drop my table too?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DROP-INDEX.html#GUID-F60F75DF-2866-4F93-BB7F-8FCE64BF67B6

Comment: It's also possible to test it by yourself by creating a sample table and index. Or even using sandbox in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJZEonEf)

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't drop a table.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table demo as select level id from dual connect by level <= 5;

Table created.
```

Index on that table:

```
SQL> create index ord_ix_demo on demo (id);

Index created.
```

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from demo;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

Drop the index:

```
SQL> drop index ord_ix_demo;

Index dropped.
```

Is table still here? Yes:

```
SQL> select * from demo;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

SQL>
```